# Applying Zorn's lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Prove that in a no trivial ring, the set of all prime ideal has minimal elements (ordered by subset inclusion).

I have thought that we can take as a lower bound of the set the ideal (0)={0} because it's the lower bound of any chain and applying Zorn's lemma we know there's a mininmal element.

I don't know if Zorn's lemma can be used in this way. Thanks.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott - "isn't **necessarily**" (zero may be a prime ideal, but it is not always a prime ideal, so the proof can't just use the zero ideal; when it is prime the problem is trivial, so the interesting case is exactly the case when you CAN'T assume it's in the partially ordered set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Lemma (Zorn)**: Let $\left({X, \preceq}\right), X \ne \varnothing$ be a non-empty ordered set such that every non-empty chain in X has an upper bound (or lower bound) in $X$. Then $X$ has at least one maximal (minimal) element.

We first need to check if **every chain has an lower bound**. Let $\mathscr{P}$ the set of all prime ideals of our ring $R$. Let $\mathfrak{p}_i\in\mathscr{P}$, $i\in I$ such that $\mathfrak{p}_i \subset \mathfrak{p}_j$ if $i > j$. Then let us define $\mathfrak{p} = \cap_{i} \mathfrak{p}_i$.

Clearly, $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal (*why ?*), and constitutes a lower bound of the chain as $\mathfrak{p}$ is contained in every $\mathfrak{p}_i$. Therefore one can apply **Zorn's Lemma**, yielding us the existence of a minimal element in $\mathscr{P}$.

**Edit :** As mentioned in the comments below, Zorn's lemma holds if $X$ is a **non-empty** ordered set. It's actually a non-trivial result that $\mathscr{P}$ is indeed non-empty. To prove this property, one can prove (or admit) for instance that **every ring $R\neq 0$ has at least one maximal ideal** using Zorn's lemma.

Comment: "Clearly" actually requires a little bit of (trivial) proof that the intersection is indeed a **prime** ideal. And for the proof to be complete, we need to know the set of prime ideals is non-empty. (Perhaps just state "we know from another application of Zorn's lemma that every non-trivial ring has **maximal** ideals, which are prime." With your edited answer, in the second paragraph, it should be "if $i > j$".

Comment: @mathguy The proof is indeed trivial, so I wanted to leave it as an exercise. Nonetheless, you're quite right about making things clearer when it comes to non-empty-ness ;).

Comment: I didn't mean necessarily to change your answer; perhaps just to state explicitly what you are leaving as exercise to the OP. That would be perfectly fine.

Comment: Nitpicking: You write $I\subset \Bbb N$, but the chains in Zorn's lemma are allowed to be longer than that or not even well-ordered (and your proof fortunately does not use $I\subset \Bbb N$)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes indeed my lord!

Comment: Why is $\mathfrak{p}$ an element of $\mathscr{P}$?  More specifically, $\mathscr{P}$ cannot contain the $0$ ideal (or else there is trivially a minimal element), but then how do you rule out $\mathfrak{p} = 0$?

Comment: Please note my last comment about "$i>j$" too.

Comment: @JasonDeVito - You don't need to treat the zero ideal separately at all. To answer your question: The proof works whether the zero ideal is prime or not. If it is not prime, the intersection is not the zero ideal, because the intersection is ALWAYS a prime ideal!

Comment: @mathguy:  I don't understand.  Let's suppose we take the view point that the zero ideal is not prime.  The intersection of non-zero prime ideals can very well be $0$.  For example, the intersection $\bigcap_{p prime} p\mathbb{Z}\subseteq \mathbb{Z}$ is the 0 ideal.  Somewhere, one must use the fact that the $\mathfrak{p}_i$ form a chain.

Comment: @mathguy:  Nevermind - my ring theory is rusty.  It is not a matter of convention as to whether the zero ideal is prime, it's a matter of whether your ring is an integral domain or not.  My bad!

Comment: @JasonDeVito - no, what you are missing is something different. The claim is not that zero (without being prime) can't be an intersection of primes. Rather, in this proof we don't have ANY intersection of primes; it is the intersection of a linearly ordered chain of smaller and smaller primes! The linear ordering is crucial in proving the intersection is a prime ideal.

Comment: @mathguy:  Well, to be fair, I missed both points ;-) To prove to myself that I am really understanding, here is a sketch that an intersection of a chain of primes is prime.  If $p = ab$ is in the intersection, then for each $i$, either $a\in \mathfrak{p}_i$ or $b$ is.  If, after some point in the decreasing sequence of $\mathfrak{p}_i$ we lose $a$, then $b$ must be in all the $\mathfrak{p}_i$ from then on.  Chainness implies $b$ is in all of them so $b$ is in the intersection.  On the other hand, if we never lose $a$, by by chainness, $a$ is in all of them, so is in the intersection.  Thanks!